# How can I convert a 1D numpy.ndarray of same-length 1D ndarrays to 2D numpy.ndarray?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I encountered with the problem that, a ndarray, with same-length 1d ndarrays as elements, cannot be converted to a 2d ndarray gracefully. The array is just like this:

```
[array([ 1.24836708, -0.00366597, -0.00617445,  0.00593824, -0.00499844,
        -0.008723  ,  0.0017313 ,  0.0032415 , -0.00921341, -0.08843152,
        -0.7156603 , -1.36149851,  1.03884429, -1.07907692, -1.08093478,
         0.40311199,  1.69189478])
 array([ 1.25213268e+00,  5.91834461e-06, -3.67174629e-03,  4.31587243e-03,
         2.05513245e-03,  4.03030160e-03, -3.70626458e-03, -3.19801204e-03,
        -4.03959450e-03, -3.16571953e-04, -3.36570170e-03,  4.23967454e-03,
        -4.80364918e-03, -5.40294083e-05, -7.57197110e-04,  8.55342504e-04,
         8.52148544e-06])
 array([  1.22506234,  -0.6000973 ,  -0.65958838,   0.01343306,
         -0.28506279,  -0.64566119,  -0.02085904,  -0.18191512,
         -2.45525694,  -1.91504442, -10.        , -10.        ,
          0.28079188,   2.70344181, -10.        ,  -4.4974326 ,
          4.82187824])
 ...
```

The shape of the array is `(256,)` (batch size). It seems like it's not recognized as a 2d array, right?
Code as follows:

```
    def sample(self, batch_size, **kwargs):
        """
        Sample a batch of experiences.
        Args:
            batch_size: int
                How many experience tuples to sample as a batch.
        Returns:
            state_batch: np.ndarray
                batch of current observed states
            action_batch: np.ndarray
                batch of actions executed given current states
            reward_batch: np.ndarray
                rewards received as results of executing action_batch
            next_state_batch: np.ndarray
                next state observed after executing action_batch
            done_mask: np.ndarray
                done_mask[i] = 1 if executing act_batch[i] resulted in the end of an episode
            discount: np.ndarray
                product of gammas for N-step returns
        """
        assert len(self._buffer) >= batch_size
        
        idx = np.random.randint(0, len(self._buffer), size=batch_size)
        batch = np.array(self._buffer)[idx]

        weights = np.zeros(batch_size)
        idxes = np.zeros(batch_size)

        return [np.array(batch[:, i]) for i in range(6)] + [weights, idxes]
```

The `self._buffer` is a list, with `[list(len=17), list(len=6), int, list(len=17), bool, int]` as element. The array I asked is actually the `np.array(batch[:, 0])`.

I tried np.array, array.reshape, but didn't work. The only way i can imagine is to flatten the array, and then reshape it.

Is there any method can convert the array to a 'common' 2d array as follows in few steps?

```
[ 1.28988438e+00 -3.28926461e-01 -3.16421640e-01  8.41842633e-03
 -6.04719630e-01 -3.21522510e-01  2.62200694e-02 -6.86004568e-01
 -2.75207792e+00  7.86307393e-01 -1.00000000e+01 -1.00000000e+01
  3.95934592e-01 -6.10089078e+00 -1.00000000e+01  5.53911043e-02
 -9.57694240e+00]
[ 1.20355496 -0.08770949  0.02464436 -0.11603001  1.19935722 -0.01665168
 -0.13457423 -0.03690821 -1.60970334  0.07964383 -5.48408598  0.10511611
 -8.75844077 -6.11991489 -2.52924686 -4.49214368  1.07501073]
[ 1.23668679e+00  1.71734326e-02  1.66840531e-02  5.26031800e-03
 -2.82087376e-02 -3.94339947e-03  2.50997621e-02  8.48180561e-02
  1.36369562e-01 -5.52168069e-01  6.43659328e-01  5.59083718e-01
  9.81923803e-03  1.00000000e+01  2.63192025e-01  8.68684414e-01
 -4.33114962e+00]
 ...
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? ```batch = np.array(self._buffer)[idx]```

Comment: Is your initial "array of numpy ndarrays" a Python list of ndarrays, or an actual ndarray of ndarrays? And what specifically are you trying to convert it to? A list of lists? An ndarray of lists? A 2D ndarray? Your question is not clear.

Comment: To fdireito, this step is to sample a batch of tuples from the _buffer, idx is a random list of indexes.

Comment: To MattDMo, thank u for your suggestions! 1. an actual ndarray of ndarrays 2. a 2d ndarray. For the problem has been solved by Charles Jackson, I will pay attention to these problems you mentioned next time!

Answer (score 0):

Let's focus on making an array from a list of arrays.

```
In [93]: alist = [np.arange(3)+i for i in range(4)]
In [94]: alist
Out[94]: [array([0, 1, 2]), array([1, 2, 3]), array([2, 3, 4]), array([3, 4, 5])]
```

If those arrays really have the same size, you'll get a numeric 2d array - that's `np.array`s preferred operation.

```
In [95]: np.array(alist)
Out[95]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [3, 4, 5]])
```

But if one (or more) array is different we get an error:

```
In [96]: alist[3] = np.arange(2)    
In [97]: np.array(alist)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[97], line 1
----> 1 np.array(alist)

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (4,) + inhomogeneous part.
```

Depending of the numpy version is might just give the object dtype array, or raise a warning, or as in the latest require a change on our part.

```
In [102]: foobar = np.array(alist, object)    
In [103]: foobar
Out[103]: 
array([array([0, 1, 2]), array([1, 2, 3]), array([2, 3, 4]),
       array([0, 1])], dtype=object)
```

This 1d object dtype, not a 2d array.  `reshape` isn't going to change that.

Even if we restore the length of the short array, we can't make a 2d array:

```
In [104]: foobar[3]=np.arange(3)    
In [105]: np.array(foobar)
Out[105]: 
array([array([0, 1, 2]), array([1, 2, 3]), array([2, 3, 4]),
       array([0, 1, 2])], dtype=object)
```

Instead we have to use some version of `concatenate`.  Here `stack` works nicely:

```
In [106]: np.stack(foobar)
Out[106]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2]])
```

Note that if I tried to use `stack` on the [103] foobar it would have raised an error.

So if you get a 1d object dtype array, but were expecting a 2d numeric array, check the element array/list sizes. Making a ragged object array is not longer a default fall back option.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I can comfirm every element arrays has the same size=17, which i have checked with `for _i in np.array(batch[:, 0]): assert _i.shape == (17,)`.